# How to aggregate a lookup in a nested property?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, lookup, aggregation

I have a Java Spring Application connected to a mongo db.

In that db, I have two collections:

atas which contains documents with following schema:

```
{
  ata: string,
  description: string
}
```

and

corrections which contains documents with following schema:

```
{
   //some properties
   predictions: [
       {ata: string, accuracy: float}
   ],
   //other properties
}
```

I want to "join" both collections on the ata property of the atas collection and the ata property of the predictions property of the corrections property so that I end up with a document with

```
{
    //some properties
    predictions: [
      {ata: string, description: string, accuracy: float}
    ]
}
```

OR

```
{

   //some properties
   predictions: [
      {ata: {ata: string, description}, accuracy: float}
   ]

}
```

How to do that in mongo ?

I used the following code to see if I could at least get the correct ata documents for each prediction.

```
db.getCollection('corrections').aggregate([
{
    $lookup: 
    {
        from: "atas",
        localField: "predictions.ata",
        foreignField: "ata",
        as: "atas"
    }
}])
```

It gives me the correct ata in the resulting documents (if it exists in the atas collection).

Now I'd like to be able to have thoses atas in the ata property of the object in the predictions property of each documents, as explained above.

Don't hesitate don't ask me questions if my request isn't clear.

Thank you in advance for any help or time you give me.

PS: I tagged with java and spring because I want to implement this in Spring but first I wanted to see how to do it in pure mongo.